# Mongodb $pull on nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `records` like this

```
{
    "recordId" : "5a65d212-774e-4208-8cb4-bf4e92e80898",
    "recordName" : "recordABC",
    "entries" : [
        {
            "formId" : "f548684e-31a7-4e63-af5c-4120670f963f",
            "formSequence" : 1,
            "fieldId" : "element1",
        },
        {
            "formId" : "f548684e-31a7-4e63-af5c-4120670f963f",
            "formSequence" : 2,
            "fieldId" : "element2",
            "value" : "notes"
        },
        {
            "formId" : "f548684e-31a7-4e63-af5c-4120670f963f",
            "formSequence" : 1,
            "fieldId" : "element3",
            "value" : [
                {
                    "originalFileName" : "fileA",
                    "thumbnail" : "thumbnailA"
                },
                {
                    "originalFileName" : "fileB",
                    "thumbnail" : "thumbnailB"
                },
                {
                    "originalFileName" : "fileC",
                    "thumbnail" : "thumbnailC"
                },
                {
                    "originalFileName" : "fileD",
                    "thumbnail" : "thumbnailD"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

I need to remove the document

```
{
    "originalFileName" : "fileC",
    "thumbnail" : "thumbnailC"
}
```

from `record.entries.value` array.

I tried with below query

```
db.records.update({ "_id" : "5a65d212-774e-4208-8cb4-bf4e92e80898" , $and : [ { "entries.formSequence" : 1} , { "entries.formId" : "f548684e-31a7-4e63-af5c-4120670f963f"} , { "entries.fieldId" : "element3"}]}, { $pull : { "entries.$.value" : { "originalFileName" : "fileC"}}});
```

It returns `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`
There is a one match, but the item with `"originalFileName" : "fileC"` is not removed

Whats is wrong with my query ? How to do this ?

Comment: Please remove all tab characters when posting to StackOverflow. The MongoDB shell does not like them for cut and paste. Thankyou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure you are matching a *specific* element in the array when using the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in an update statement. [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) does generally not cut it, what you need for multiple fields of an array element is [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```js
db.records.update(
    { 
        "recordId": "5a65d212-774e-4208-8cb4-bf4e92e80898", 
        "entries": {
            "$elemMatch": { 
                "formSequence": 1,
                "formId" : "f548684e-31a7-4e63-af5c-4120670f963f",
                "fieldId" : "element3"
             }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$pull" : { 
            "entries.$.value" : { "originalFileName" : "fileB"}
        }
    }
)
```

This makes sure that the "position" of the matched operator is the one that matches **all** for the conditions for that elements properties that you specify.

The main problem with [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) in this case ( and also not necessary since you are not asking for multiple conditions on the same field, so it is really an *implicit* statement, which MongoDB just does ) is that you are not matching the conditions on the **same** element. All that is being done is making sure that *all* the conditions actually match *somewhere* in the document, and therefore in *any* element.

You could write in this way as well, which will not return the correct result:

```js
db.records.update(
    { 
        "recordId": "5a65d212-774e-4208-8cb4-bf4e92e80898", 
        "entries.formSequence": 1,
        "entries.formId" : "f548684e-31a7-4e63-af5c-4120670f963f",
        "entries.fieldId" : "element3"
    }, 
    { 
        "$pull" : { 
            "entries.$.value" : { "originalFileName" : "fileB"}
        }
    }
)
```

Perfectly valid in syntax and the same as what you have written, but of course it does not select the *correct* element for the result you want in the update statement.

So it is `$elemMatch` that makes *sure* that **all** of those conditions are present on the same element within the array. This is what you want, as it performs an individual "query" on *each* element of the array to make sure those conditions match.

Comment: It worked. Thank You. But, I didn't understand what is wrong with the $and operator in my query.

Comment: @faizi Fair enough. Edited with more information that should explain the distinction between the two approaches.